# How to manage env variables and secrets?

Tags: security, environment-variables

Boy, I'm tired of this topic. I have gitlab CI, local environments, keychain, keepass, gcp, aws and a whole bunch of other places where some of my env variables stored. Furthermore, Expo apps, for example, can't pull .env files, so I have to write bash scripts to create js files. This hurts my brain.

I want to have a cozy place where I store all my variables and secrets safely per project per environment. I want to share it with my team, CI servers etc. I want to just specify a single key: the environemnt title. And all the variables should be pulled from somewhere. Is there such tool anywhere on the github or internet???

Not sure if this question is suitable for stackoverflow, pls direct me to the right stackexchange forum if it doesn't.

Comment: In the kubernetes world, this is really useful: https://github.com/bitnami-labs/sealed-secrets. Perhaps there is something similar albeit more generic you could make use of.

Comment: Kuberenetes clusters are expensive and too troublesome to deal with. Anything else?

Comment: Yip, sorry was not suggesting you move to k8s for the sake of good secrets management. Did you look at git-crypt at all?

Comment: git-crypt is also complicated

Comment: this is something everyone needs. I can't believe there is no user-friendly solution. I don't want to mess around with lots of configs, servers and terminals to get this working on each project. I want something to work out of the box.

Comment: I'm afraid this is off-topic here, but the thing you are looking for is called a secret vault, and there are both commercial and free solutions of different complexity.  Mozilla SOPS is a simpler free one, and I don't want to advertise commercial ones but there is a good and well-known enterprise grade one with its name starting with hash. :) (And countless others ofc.)

Comment: Check out https://github.com/sniptt-official/snip-cli. Might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Encrypt files and deployment scripts file by file, push them to repo. Whenever you need to switch environment, just decrypt the files with a the environment key word in name:

Encrypt.sh

```
# sh encrypt.sh ./config.production.js passwordhere
echo "encrypting $1"
openssl enc -aes-128-cbc -a -salt -pass pass:$2 -in $1 -out $1.enc
rm $1
mv $1.enc $1
echo "done"
```

decrypt.sh:

```
# sh decrypt.sh production passwordhere
echo "decrypting $1 environment"

for file in $(find . -not -path "*/node_modules/*" -name "*.$1*")
do
    echo "decrypting $file to ${file//.$1}"
    openssl enc -aes-128-cbc -a -d -salt -pass pass:$2 -in $file -out "${file//.$1}"
done
```